# Adding JCenter into Intellij IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jcenter

I need to add https://jcenter.bintray.com/ into IntelliJ IDEA. IJ should be able to find and update packages from JCenter as it does for Maven Central.

Currently when I add the URL to the list of maven repos, it complains "No repositories found".

[image: settings screen shot]

Note: I use the **internal IJ build system**, there is no Maven or Gradle there (and I have my reasons not to use them)

Comment: found something, not sure if it is related: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9196

Answer (score 2):

JCenter is not currently supported by IntelliJ IDEA. See this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-154970

Comment: That issue is marked as 'completed' now (status 'Fixed').  Certainly as of 2020.1, IntelliJ IDEA includes JCenter by default.